# Google verification code is visible above my site's header

Tags: header, footer

Google verification code is visible above my site's header and footer. I want to remove google verification code line from my website https://teamco.work/ .

I try to find google verification code from backend but it couldn't find,  I want to remove google verification code line from my website https://teamco.work/ header and footer.

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what framework your co is using for that site. Beyond that please provide minimal reproducible example with reference of what framworks/parts are.